# JavaScript updating only after 2-3 seconds?

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML table where I wanted to introduce sorting and search options and therefore I used Jquery which has JS & CSS file

The table is giving the correct output but whenever the page is loaded, first the table is updating without above js and css and only after 2-3 seconds, the above Jquery is updated. How can I make it fast so that it does not awkward for the user ?

Here is the HTML Code

```
{% load function %}

<!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href='media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css'>
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});</script>

<table id='example' class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Stock</th>
            <th>Open</th>
            <th>High</th>
            <th>Low</th>
            <th>Close</th>
            <th>Volume</th>
            <th>Buyers</th>
            <th>Sellers</th>
            <th>Close_open</th>
            <th>Close_high</th>
            <th>high_open</th>
            <th>high_low</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="people">
        {% for x,y in info.items %}
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">{{x|split}}</td>
            <td id= 'open{{x}}'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'open'}}</td>
            <td id='high{{x}}'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'high'}}</td>
            <td id='low{{x}}'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'low'}}</td>
            <td id='close{{x}}'>{{y|access_dictionary:'ohlc'|access_dictionary:'close'}}</td>
            <td>{{y|access_dictionary:'volume'}}</td>
            <td id='buyquantity{{x}}'>{{y|access_dictionary:'buy_quantity'}}</td>
            <td id='sellquantity{{x}}'>{{y|access_dictionary:'sell_quantity'}}</td>
            <td id='Close_open{{x}}'></td>
            <td id='Close_high{{x}}'></td>
            <td id='high_open{{x}}'></td>
            <td id='high_low{{x}}'></td>

            <script>
                // console.log(document.getElementById('high{{x}}').innerHTML)
                // console.log(document.getElementById('low{{x}}').innerHTML)
                // console.log(document.getElementById('open{{x}}').innerHTML)
                
                d = document.getElementById('close{{x}}').innerHTML - document.getElementById('open{{x}}').innerHTML
                e = document.getElementById('close{{x}}').innerHTML - document.getElementById('high{{x}}').innerHTML
                f = document.getElementById('high{{x}}').innerHTML - document.getElementById('open{{x}}').innerHTML
                g = document.getElementById('high{{x}}').innerHTML - document.getElementById('low{{x}}').innerHTML

                document.getElementById('Close_open{{x}}').innerHTML = Math.round(d * 100)/100;
                document.getElementById('Close_high{{x}}').innerHTML = Math.round(e * 100)/100;
                document.getElementById('high_open{{x}}').innerHTML = Math.round(f * 100)/100;
                document.getElementById('high_low{{x}}').innerHTML = Math.round(g * 100)/100;

                
            </script>
        </tr>
        
        {% endfor %}
        
    </tbody>
    
    
</table>


<!-- <script>

    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.reload(1);
    },2000);
</script> -->

<style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: none;
        width: 20%;

    }

    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 2px 8px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    th {
        background-color: #C8C8C8;
        cursor: pointer;
        width:100px;
    }
</style>
```

Here `{% for x,y in info.items %}` info is the dictionary where all stock related information is stored. Therefore I have run a loop to display it on a webpage. Please reply

Comment: Please share more details. Does this happen due to loading other components, due to anything in the code that contains a waiting period,....?

Comment: Please post relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the file if (linked):

```
<script id="update" src="yourfile.js"></script>
<script>
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var e = '';
  if (i == 1) {
    e = '?random=1234';
  } else {
    e = '?random=123456';
  }
  window.update.src += e; 
}
</script>
```

Or if the file is an absolute url,like "http://www.example.com" and your url is different, try putting the file in your directory. Try setting cache if it is disabled on your page because then it can get the file easier.